# Is it possible to compile go code without builtin library that can run on a machine without operating system

Tags: go

Like C compile flags `-fno-pic -O -nostdinc -c -static -fno-builtin -fno-strict-aliasing -m32 -fno-stack-protector` can compile codes into pure ELF without library rely on unique system. Is there a possible way GO can do that?

Comment: An ELF binary still requires an operating system to execute. A binary that doesn't rely on an OS would be a [unikernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unikernel), which is no small undertaking.

Answer (score 2):

Simple answer is no. Go relies on the operating system (Windows, linux, macOS, BSD). Go has a runtime designed to work on specific environments https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/MinimumRequirements.

There are some open source projects that will help you achieve it, but I wouldn't put them in production as they support a limited number of hardware chips and they are not supported in the same way as the standard library. Some examples are:

https://github.com/ziutek/emgo

https://github.com/tinygo-org/tinygo

These frameworks/libraries will help you run Go code on bare metal.